# JSONObject losing Values

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following code

```
    JSONArray photos = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject imageInfo = new JSONObject();
    try {
        imageInfo.put("ImageType", image.getImageType());
        imageInfo.put("RegNo", image.getRegNo());
        imageInfo.put("ImageName", image.getImageName());
        imageInfo.put("ImageClass", image.getImageClass());
        imageInfo.put("ImageData", base64ImageData);
        imageInfo.put("EnquiryID", image.getEnquiryID());
        imageInfo.put("VehicleID", image.getVehicleID());
        photos.put(imageInfo);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, when I the code reach the line to add the "base64ImageData", which is a very long string, the JSON object "imageInfo" lose all the other keys and values, so it left with only the "imageData" kay and its value.

Any help thanks.

Comment: how do you read the object aftermath?

Comment: @Onheiron  'imageInfo.toString();' and print it out.

Comment: You can print the Information in using print statement in java and logs in Android using : e.g Log.i("info",photos.toString()) or System.out.println(photos.toString());

Comment: well, if it is a long string it might be cut off in the console... what happens if you print out imageInfo.getString("ImageType")?

Comment: @RohitHeera  I did print it out and imageInfo has only the image data "ImageData" key and its value, also when I print out the Array photos, it has only one object, but when I debug it I can see there are more then one.

Comment: you need to implement loop to add multiple values in JsonArray object

Comment: @Onheiron Thanks man, you were correct, the string was cut on the console. Thanks a lot :)